# Refining perl code for sliding window approach

Tags: perl, sliding-window

I am working with a file (fasta file), here is the format-

```
>chr1
AACCCCCCCCTCCCCCCGCTTCTGGCCACAGCACTTAAACACATCTCTGC
CAAACCCCAAAAACAAAGAACCCTAACACCAGCCTAACCAGATTTCAAAT
TTTATCTTTAGGCGGTATGCACTTTTAACAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
GCCCATCCTACCCAGCACACACACACCGCTGCTAACCCCATACCCCGAAC
CAACCAAACCCCAAAGACACCCCCCACAGTTTATGTAGCTTACCTCNNNN
>chrM
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCAT
TTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTG
GAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTCATT
CTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACCTACTA
AAGTGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTGAAT
GTCTGCACAGCCGCTTTCCACACAGACATCATAACAAAANAATTTCCACC
```

I want to use sliding window approach (non overlapping windows, size =50). I want to find the coordinates for each character with in 50bp window but not including N's. The output for first chr1 should be->

```
chr1   0       50
chr1   50      100
chr1   100     215 
chr1   215     265
```

The code  is -

```
use warnings; 
*ARGV or die "No input file specified";
open *first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
$start=1;
while(<first>) {
    chomp;
    if ( /(>)(\w)/ ) {   #taking lines which have name of chromosome
    @arr=split(">");  #splitting at ">" character and in $arr[1], there is chr name now


        if (defined @array){

            foreach (@array){
            $length++;      

                if($_ ne N){
                    $non++;
                    if ($non == 50){

                    print $chr,"\t",$start,"\t",$length,"\n";
                    $start=$length;
                    $non=0;

                    }
                }       
            }
        }

        undef @array;  
        $length=0;
        $non=0;
        $start=0;
    }

    else {

        @count=split(//, $_); #splitting each character in line

        push(@array,@count);  #storing each character in array till we find next chromosome

        $chr=$arr[1];
    } 

}




foreach (@array){
        $length++;

          if($_ ne N){
          $non++;
               if ($non == 50){

        print $chr,"\t",$start,"\t",$length,"\n";
        $start=$length;
        $non=0;

               }
          }

}
```

The thing is my fasta file is big and this code is taking lot of memory and time. Can you please give suggestions how can I make it fast using less memory.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but it will help clear your script up a bit. If you follow the `strict` pragma and declare all new variables, such as `@array`, `$length`, `$non`, and `$start`, with `my`, they will automatically jump out of scope and you won't have to keep `undef`ing and resetting them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with my and use strict in the beginning and when ever I have to print that variable in some other loop, then it shows error (use of uninitialized....). So I skip use strict part.

Comment: what is that foreach at the end actually doing? It looks like it is just duplicated code...

Comment: It is for printing last @array, for last chromosome (when while loop ends).

Comment: @vikas: if it says you're using an uninitialized variable, don't disable `strict`, fix your code! The use of `strict` is made to help  you debug; if you disregard this facility, don't come ask for help with broken code when the compiler is telling you it's broken.

Comment: @Raphink: The code is not broken, it is working. I got irritated by the error when I was using strict, so I skipped it and then it worked. But I got your point. I know strict is very important and I will be careful. Thanks

Comment: you can use `no warnings "uninitialized";` after `use strict; use warnings;` This means that you get all of the other benefits of s/w without those warnings, which others have complained about too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, especially when you are asking for help with it. It will save a lot of time by finding many simple mistakes for you.

From where did you get the idea to use typeglobs in this way? `*ARGV` is *always* true so it is useless for testing whether `@ARGV` is empty, and using `*first` as a filehandle will work but it is very unusual. Best is the lexical filehandle, like this

```
open my $first, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

However there is no need to explicitly open the file specified as a parameter: Perl will do this implicitly for you if you read from the null filehandle `<>`.

This program appears to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use constant WINDOW => 50;

@ARGV or die "No input file specified";

my ($key, $pos, $start, $size);

while (<>) {

  if ( /^>(.+?)\s/ ) {
    $key = $1;
    $pos = $size = 0;
    undef $start;
    next;
  }

  chomp;

  for (split //) {
    next unless /[ATGC]/;
    $start //= $pos;
    $size++;
    if ($key and $size == WINDOW) {
      printf "%-6s %4d %4d\n", $key, $start, $pos + 1;
      undef $start;
      $size = 0;
    }
  }
  continue {
    $pos++;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
chr1      0   50
chr1     50  100
chr1    100  215
chr1    215  265
chrM      0   50
chrM     50  100
chrM    100  150
chrM    150  200
chrM    200  250
```

Comment: Since `N` (unknown bases) should not be counted for the 50 base pair window, you might have to analyze more than one input row.

Comment: @dgw: Thanks - I didn't notice I was out of sync with the required output. But the problem was just that I was displaying the wrong values. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting an error Search pattern not terminated -> at this line $start //= $pos;.

Comment: @Vikas: you must be on an old version of Perl. The `//` operator was introduced in Perl v5.10 in 2007. Upgrade, or replace that line with `defined $start or $start = $pos;`

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. I am little bit confused about $key=$1. This key contains chromosome name i:e >chr1 or >chrM. But when you are printing $key, it is printing only chr1 or chrM without ">" (which is totally fine for me). I just want to know, at which line you are throwing ">" away?

Comment: @Vikas: the regular expression is `/^>(.+?)\s/` which matches a right angle bracket at the beginning of the string, followed by one or more characters up to the first whitespace character. Ony the *one or more characters* are within parentheses, and it is this that is captured into `$1`, having the effect of stripping the angle bracket and any trailing spaces, tabs or linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the code to output the data twice I moved it into a subroutine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

if( ! @ARGV  ) {
  die "No input file specified";
}

open my $file , '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
my ( $chromosome , $start ) = ( undef , 1 ) ;

my @array = () ;
while(<$file>) {
  chomp;

  if ( m/^>(\w+)/ ) { # New chromosome
    my $new_chromosome = $1 ; # Save the new chromosome name temporarily
    if( @array ) {
      split_sequence( $chromosome , \@array ) ;
    }
    @array = () ;
    $chromosome = $new_chromosome ;
  } else {
    push @array , split( // ) ;
  }
}

split_sequence( $chromosome , \@array ) if @array ;

sub split_sequence {
  my ( $chromosome , $arrayref ) = @_ ;

  printf "%-10.10s  %d (total length)\n" , $chromosome , $#{ $arrayref } ;
  my ( $start , $nonN ) = ( 0 , 0 ) ;
  for( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#{ $arrayref } ; $i++ ) {
    if( $arrayref->[$i] ne 'N' ) {
      $nonN++ ;
      if( $nonN == 50 ) {
        printf "%-10.10s  %8d  %8d\n" , $chromosome , $start , $i ;
        $start = $i + 1 ;
        $nonN = 0 ;
      }
    }
  }
  if( $#{ $arrayref } > $start ) { # Incomplete window leftover ...
                                   # less than 50 bases long
    printf "%-10.10s  %8d  %8d **\n" , $chromosome , $start , $#{ $arrayref } ;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
perl SO002.pl SO002.fasta
chr1             299 (total length)
chr1               0        49
chr1              50        99
chr1             100       214
chr1             215       264
chr1             265       299 **
chrM             300 (total length)
chrM               0        49
chrM              50        99
chrM             100       149
chrM             150       199
chrM             200       249
chrM             250       300
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will try your code and try to understand it. Then I will come back to you, if I will struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the Bio::SeqIO module to parse the fasta file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

use constant WINDOW => 50;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file   => "fasta.txt" ,
                          -format => 'Fasta');

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    my $count = 0;
    my $beg_pos = 0;
    local $_ = $seq->seq;
    while (/(.)/g) {
        ++$count if $1 =~ /[TAGC]/;

        if ($count == WINDOW) {
            $count = 0;
            printf "%s %d %d\n", $seq->id, $beg_pos, pos() - 1;
            $beg_pos = pos();
        }
        elsif (pos == length) { # have read last char in string
            printf "%s %d %d\n", $seq->id, $beg_pos, pos() - 1;
        }
    }
}
```